# Python file path and size

Tags: python, linux, file, path, size

I've been trying to list all the files in a directory and it's subdirectory, its path and its size in python.
Somehow only the files in its directory is displayed and not the files in the subdirectories.

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize,abspath, isfile

fo=open("Size Listing.txt","a")


def size_list(mypath):
f = []
for (dirpath, dirname, filenames) in os.walk(mypath):
    f.extend(filenames)

for i in f:
    fo.write("\nPath: ")
    fo.write(abspath(i))
    fo.write(" Size: ")
    fo.write(str(getsize(join(mypath,i))))
    fo.write(" bytes")


fo.close()
```

Can someone help me out here?
Also can anyone suggest how to make a data structure in Python for the file path and size, since I need to do some sorting as well.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize

def size_list(mypath):
    with open("PathTest.txt","w") as of:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
            for f in files:
                fo.write("\nPath: " +  os.path.join(root, f))
                fo.write("\tSize: " +  str(getsize(os.path.join(root, f))) + " bytes")

size_list("path/to/dir")
```

for data structure you can use list of tuple of (Path, size) as :

```
def size_list(mypath):
    my_list = []
    with open("PathTest.txt","w") as of:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
            for f in files:
                my_file = os.path.join(root, f)
                file_size = getsize(my_file)
                my_list.append((my_file, file_size))
                fo.write("\nPath: " +  my_file)
                fo.write("\tSize: " +  str(file_size) + " bytes")
```

Comment: path/to/dir is used for appending the path?